# Multiple session ids are getting created for multiple requests when one thread is executed using Jmeter(Performance Testing)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Our application is based on asp.net, i have taken a scenario 
for which i got 15 requests when one thread being used and was trying for correlation
(dynamic values), correlated Viewstate,
Viewstategenarator,Event Validation using regular 
expression extractor(i did not correlated session id 
because it is with the path but not avaliable in parameters tab) and also added debug sampler.

I used 1 thread and 10secs rampup for running the script.
i verified request and response in view result tree.
I found that a new sessionid is getting created for every request and response.

How to get all the requests with same session id when one thread is executed?

Comment: i have added http cache manager, http cookie manager, still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

For 1 Thread to save session Id from cookie and use it in next requests you need to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)  under your Test Plan.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to correlate SESSIONID, it can be done either manually by extracting it from the URL via [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

However better idea would be using Using the [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-http-url-re-writing-modifier) which is designed for handling dynamic parameters being a part of the request URL.